# Inserting an item after specific array pattern

Tags: php, arrays, key, pattern-matching

I would like to insert an item after a specific pattern. In my case I would like to insert `x` after every second `a` in an array. After six'th `a` my code does not work properly:

```
$array = array("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","a","a");

$out = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
    $out[] = $value; // add current letter to new array
    if($value=='a' && $array[$key-1]=='a' && $out[$key] !='x'){ // check if current and last letter are a
        $out[] = 'x'; // if so add an x to the array
    }
}

print_r($out);
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat regexps are for strings.

Comment: I thought he want to add `a` after every `x`, didn't saw array.

Comment: @u_mulder, regex can be used here, actually. please, see my answer.

Comment: @sevavietl and what if OP shows us simplified example. What if instead of `"a"` he has objects? Other array?

Comment: @u_mulder, sorry, I didn't have an impression that we are reading tea leaves. But, anyway, I specified **use regular expression in this particular situation**. I completely agree that in more complex situations this approach wouldn't work. But if the task is as simple as it was stated, there is no need to reinvent the regex and juggle with loops.

Comment: @u_mulder, in fact, it will work on any one-dimensional array of strings. And if you want to change insertion pattern, you will simply change regex, without the need of altering any conditions.

Comment: @u_mulder yes, it is actually a simplified example. Instead of "a" I really use another array...

Comment: @u_mulder, touche.

Answer (score 1):

> Correct answer at the end

Is it that what are you looking for?

```
<?php
$array = array("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","a","a");
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    if ($key == 0 || $key == 1) {
        $array[$key] = $value; 
    } elseif($array[$key-1] == 'a' && $array[$key-2] == 'a' && $array[$key] == 'a') {
        $array[$key] = 'x';
    } else {
        $array[$key] = $value; 
    }
}
$count = count($array);
if ($array[$count-1] == 'a' && $array[$count-2] == 'a') {
    $array[] = 'x';
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

If I understand correctly, after 2 `a` you want to put `x` into new array.

**UPDATE**

Please check now. There will be added a new element `x` if last two are `a` in array.

With exceptions, but still working:

```
<?php
$array = array("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","a","a");
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    if($array[$key-1] == 'a' && $array[$key-2] == 'a' && $array[$key] == 'a') {
        $array[$key] = 'x';
    }
}
$count = count($array);
if ($array[$count-1] == 'a' && $array[$count-2] == 'a') {
    $array[] = 'x';
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

**UPDATE - Correct code**

I think code below will fit all your needs:

```
<?php
$arr = array("a","w","a","d","a","a","b","a","a", "w");
$arr_count = count($arr);   
for ($i = 0; $i < $arr_count; $i++){
    if (!empty($arr[$i+1]) && $arr[$i] == $arr[$i+1]) {
        $first_half = array_slice($arr, 0, $i+2);
        $second_half = array_slice($arr, $i+2, $arr_count);     
        if (count($second_half) > 0) {
            $arr = array_merge($first_half, ["x"], $second_half);
        }
    }
}
$count = count($arr);
if ($arr[$count-1] == 'a' && $arr[$count-2] == 'a') {
    $arr[] = 'x';
}

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly but for the last two `a` `x` is not inserted.

Comment: I will add just one more if, and if it will be last two element in array as `a` it will add in array a new element `x`.

Comment: Please check now. We are adding new element `x` if last two are `a` in array.

Comment: You have a few conditions in your task, so I think it's not really long. All job is done in that little `foreach`. Anyway if it fits your needs, it would be great if you accept my answer. Also I added some code, but it will cause exceptions, which I dont think you want, and changed main code to be a bit shorter.

Comment: if I have just the pattern `array("a","a","b");` the `b` gets replaced by `x` in both codes

Comment: It shouldnt? It is after `a, a`

Comment: You just have to add in `if` `&& $array[$key] == 'a'`. I have updated my answer. Check now then, and if it's okay it would be great if you accept my answer.

Comment: Now it is the other way round. For `array("a","a","b");` no `x`is inserted.

Comment: Because the last 2 arent `a, a`. You have many statements which we don't know.

Comment: I am just looking for a code where a certain pattern never mind where it is and how often it appears is located and after it a character is inserted.

Comment: So you want to `push` x instead of replacing ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to insert x no matter how it is inserted

Comment: Fine, I will prepare code tomorrow but I hope you will accept my answer if it will work then

Comment: I think I found a solution, please check latest update :)

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the comment, you sure can use regular expression in this particular situation:

```
$pattern = '/a{2}/';
$replacement = '$0x';

$out = str_split(preg_replace(
    $pattern,
    $replacement,
    implode('', $array)
));
```

Basically, we gluing the characters together (using [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)) to form the string and then replacing every `"aa"` with `"aax"`. After that we split string back to the array using [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e89a6248261d68e5ee279472bc645db6c75c65a8).

Comment: It is not the most elegant way to solve my problem because we glue it together and split it again...

Comment: @MoeJoe, the word elegant in this context is so ambiguous, that you can call almost anything either "elegant" or "not elegant". Which makes the semantic load of your comment equal to zero.